# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when deploying on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this problem happens when trying to deploy on heroku, I figured it could be the master.key, I redid the project from scratch and the same error occurred. I'm a JS dev, and I'm studying hard to learn RoR.
thanks
I minimize the code error

```
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
/app/config/environments/production.rb:124:in `block in <main>'
...
`perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.5/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I refactor all. try a new repository, master.key new .

this is my production.rb

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/time'

# rubocop: disable Metrics/BlockLength
Rails.application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  config.active_storage.service = :local

  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [:request_id]

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log disallowed deprecations.
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation = :log

  # Tell Active Support which deprecation messages to disallow.
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation_warnings = []

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new


  if ENV['RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT'].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false


  # Email
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    host: 'https://max-api-on-rails.herokuapp.com/'
  }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain:'gmail.com',
    user_name: Rails.application.credentials.zoho[:user_name],
    password: Rails.application.credentials.zoho[:password],
    authentication: 'login',
    ssl: true,
    tls: true,
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
end
```

Comment: Is that `perform` from some background job? Is there anything else in the stacktrace?

Comment: yes, the code error is to long, but, it's a pattern of this type of error according to what I researched, so I think it doesn't say much. but i could be wrong.

Comment: I can't tell you much without seeing more details, but check the two tasks that are being executed `db:migrate` and `db:load_config`, try executing those in your local environment and see if the same error happens

Comment: This looks like the `config/database.yml` does not have any configuration data for the environment it's being deployed in, as in it could be missing the `production:` key. I don't know why this error isn't presented better.

Comment: What is the nil referring to that is described here: `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I omitted important details from the code. I edited the question now, I believe it is clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Error is email smtp configuration. i using zoho, but my credentials is gmail.